# HTML5 Ajax JQuery PHP MySQL Insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Can anyone tell me, why I am still redirected to insertInput.php after pushing the submit button. I tried several things, but it didn't work, like changing the type from "submit" to "button" and so on.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Barocker's Song Voting</title>
        <link href="vote.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#insert").click(function(){
                    var url = "insertInput.php";
                    var data = $("#form :input").serializeArray();
                    alert("Button clicked");
                    $.post(
                        url,
                        data,
                        function(info){
                            $("#result").html(info);
                        }
                    );
                    clearInput();
                });
                function clearInput(){
                    $("#form :input").each(function(){
                        $(this).val("");
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="insertBanner">
            <form id="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Titel" autofocus required>
                <input type="url" id="url" name="url" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Link (Youtube, etc.)">
                <button id="insert">Hinzufügen</button>
            </form>
            <span id="result"></span>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
    /*
     * Connect to MySQL
     */

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "@", "", "test");

    /*
     * Check Connection
     */

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO barocker (title, url) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $url . "')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        echo "Success";
    }

    /*
     *  Close Connection
     */

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Thank you guys. Any help as always very appreciated.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning two events for submitting one form. In HTML, there is an `action`. And in Javascript,there is an `onClick`. One way to avoid this, you can disable the `action` like this:

```
<form id="form" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
```

In PHP code, you are getting the script name of the `$("#form").attr('action')` in the following part:

**Before:**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.post(
       $("#form").attr('action'),
       data,function(info){
       $("#result").html(info);
   });
   clearInput();
});
```

Now there isn't a valid value in the `action`, this need to be altered, for example:

**After:**

```
$("#insert").click(function(){
    var url = "insertInput.php";
    $.post(
           url,
           data,function(info){
           $("#result").html(info);
    });
    clearInput();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that. Now nothing happens when I click the button: no redirect, no clear, no new entry in the db.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It added several codes above. The target element for click event should be `$("#insert")` not `$("#submit")` because the id of your submit button is `'insert'`.

Comment: Edit my initial post, and did what you wrote, but like I said, the button doesn't work anymore, nothing executed.

Comment: I copied your code into JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/K8h8T/2/. And the button seems to work well. When you click the button, an alert message will be shown.

Comment: Okay, the problem was, that I forgot $(document).read(function(){}); I edited my initial Post, to show how it works.

Answer (score 2):

you need #insert click disable as i understand

```
$("#insert").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Still redirecting to insertInput.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $("#form :input").serializeArray();
            $.post(
                $("#form").attr('action'),
                data,
                function(info){
                    $("#result").html(info);
                }
            );
            clearInput();
        });
```

`e.preventDefault();` This instruction prevents default action

Comment: change, `$("#submit").click()` to `$("#input").click()` or `$("input[type=submit]").click()`